# Webpacker can't find application.js in manifest.json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I just make a new rails app with versions

Rails = 6.1.3

Ruby = 2.7.2

webpacker = 5.2.1

Everything was fine but when I generate Room Scaffold and want to visit localhost:3000/rooms
Some error occurs

> Failed to load /config/webpack/development.js' config

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

> Webpacker can't find application.js in manifest.json

Here is my full error screen
[image: Error screen]

And when I execute

```html
bundle exec rake webpacker:install
```

It failed by some errors occurs on the image below

[image: Ist image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have application.js under packs?

Comment: yes @razvans i have, i did nothing, but just generate app by rails new command and generate a scaffold and I updated my question please have a look

Comment: remove node_modules, package-lock.json, install all the dependencies that raise errors in yarn install. Then post an update.

Comment: @razvans I already tried that & today I notice that actually error occurs during my app creating time, I post another question related to this please have a look.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66487941/node-modules-node-sass-command-failed