# node_modules/node-sass: Command failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, node-modules, ruby-on-rails-6

Recently I created many rails apps but today when I try to create a new app by

`rails new chat_room`

I'm stuck with some errors

> error /home/humayun/projects/chat_room2/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed

> failed Error: not found: /usr/bin/python

Here is the full error screen

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

Moreover, my python version is 3.9.2

And node version is v15.10.0

Comment: See if this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571257/cant-find-python-executable-python